# Is there any way to enable swipe feature for tab screens in compose without using pager?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-tabs

I have implemented tab in an activity using jetpack compose and based on selected tab, i am displaying different screens. I need to implement swipe functionality for screens but i don't want to use pager that is available in accompanist. Is there any way to do that?